# Font Awesome Plus Inside Circle Only Showing the Circle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I'm using Font Awesome with a Bootstrap 4 Accordion and trying to display a plus with a circle around it, which should toggle to a minus with a circle around it but I'm only seeing the circle. This is the first part of my accordion with the fa icons:

```
<div id="accordion" class="my-accordion">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    My Heading
                    <span class="fa-stack fa-sm">
                        <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-plus fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                    </span>
                </button>
            </h2>
        </div>
     ...
```

Then using this jquery code to toggle the icons:

```
$("#accordion").on("hide.bs.collapse show.bs.collapse", e => {
        $(e.target)
          .prev()
          .find("i:last-child")
          .toggleClass("fa-minus fa-plus");
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. In case anyone else has the same issue, you could reference my updated code. It shows a plus inside a circle and toggles to a minus inside a circle:

```
<div id="accordion" class="my-accordion">
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h2 class="mb-0">
            <button class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                My Heading
                <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i>
            </button>
        </h2>
    </div>
 ...
```

Place this jquery code after the accordion:

```
$("#accordion").on("hide.bs.collapse show.bs.collapse", e => {
        $(e.target)
          .prev()
          .find("i:last-child")
        .toggleClass("fa fa-minus-circle fa-lg  fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg");

    });
```

Comment: This suggests that you didn't load all of Bootstrap's JavaScript code. What does your index.html where you load the prerequisite files look like?